# Trouble fitting simple data with MLPRegressor

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am trying out Python and scikit-learn. I cannot get MLPRegressor to come even close to the data. Where is this going wrong?

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.0, 1, 0.01).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x).ravel()

reg = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(10,),  activation='relu', solver='adam',    alpha=0.001,batch_size='auto',
               learning_rate='constant', learning_rate_init=0.01, power_t=0.5, max_iter=1000, shuffle=True,
               random_state=None, tol=0.0001, verbose=False, warm_start=False, momentum=0.9,
               nesterovs_momentum=True, early_stopping=False, validation_fraction=0.1, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999,
               epsilon=1e-08)

reg = reg.fit(x, y)

test_x = np.arange(0.0, 1, 0.05).reshape(-1, 1)
test_y = reg.predict(test_x)

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(x, y, s=10, c='b', marker="s", label='real')
ax1.scatter(test_x,test_y, s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='NN Prediction')

plt.show()
```

The result is not very good:
[image: failed fit]
Thank you.

Comment: Here is a tutorial that I wrote with Keras (TensorFlow) and Gekko with the simple sine wave example: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DeepLearning This may be useful for those who would like to compare with the already very good solutions posted here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are too few points to fit for this non-nonlinear model, so the fit is sensitive to the seed. A good seed helps, but it is not known a priori. You can also add more data points.

By iterating through various seeds, I determined `random_state=9` to work well. Surely there are others.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.0, 1, 0.01).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x).ravel()

nn = MLPRegressor(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(10,),  activation='relu', solver='adam', alpha=0.001, batch_size='auto',
    learning_rate='constant', learning_rate_init=0.01, power_t=0.5, max_iter=1000, shuffle=True,
    random_state=9, tol=0.0001, verbose=False, warm_start=False, momentum=0.9, nesterovs_momentum=True,
    early_stopping=False, validation_fraction=0.1, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)

n = nn.fit(x, y)
test_x = np.arange(0.0, 1, 0.05).reshape(-1, 1)
test_y = nn.predict(test_x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(x, y, s=1, c='b', marker="s", label='real')
ax1.scatter(test_x,test_y, s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='NN Prediction')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here are the absolute errors of fits for seed integers `i = 0..9`:

```
print(i, sum(abs(test_y - np.sin(2 * np.pi * test_x).ravel())))
```

which yields:

```
0 13.0874999193
1 7.2879574143
2 6.81003360188
3 5.73859777885
4 12.7245375367
5 7.43361211586
6 7.04137436733
7 7.42966661997
8 7.35516939164
9 2.87247035261
```

Now, we can still improve fitting even with `random_state=0` by increasing number of target points from 100 to 1000 and the size of hidden layers from 10 to 100:

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.0, 1, 0.001).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x).ravel()

nn = MLPRegressor(
    hidden_layer_sizes=(100,),  activation='relu', solver='adam', alpha=0.001, batch_size='auto',
    learning_rate='constant', learning_rate_init=0.01, power_t=0.5, max_iter=1000, shuffle=True,
    random_state=0, tol=0.0001, verbose=False, warm_start=False, momentum=0.9, nesterovs_momentum=True,
    early_stopping=False, validation_fraction=0.1, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08)

n = nn.fit(x, y)
test_x = np.arange(0.0, 1, 0.05).reshape(-1, 1)
test_y = nn.predict(test_x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(x, y, s=1, c='b', marker="s", label='real')
ax1.scatter(test_x,test_y, s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='NN Prediction')
plt.show()
```

Yielding:
[image]

Btw, some parameters are unnecessary in your `MLPRegressor()`, such as `momentum`, `nesterovs_momentum`, etc. Check documentation. Also, it helps to seed your examples to make sure the results are reproducible ;)

Answer (score 18):

You just need to

- change the solver to `'lbfgs'`. The default`'adam'` is a SGD-like method, which is effective for large & messy data but pretty useless for this kind of smooth & small data.
- use a smooth activation function such as `tanh`. `relu` is almost linear, not suited for learning this simple non-linear function.

Here're the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzEUm.png) and the complete code. Even just 3 hidden neurons can achieve very high accuracy.

```
from sklearn.neural_network import MLPRegressor
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(0.0, 1, 0.01).reshape(-1, 1)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * x).ravel()

nn = MLPRegressor(hidden_layer_sizes=(3), 
                  activation='tanh', solver='lbfgs')

n = nn.fit(x, y)
test_x = np.arange(-0.1, 1.1, 0.01).reshape(-1, 1)
test_y = nn.predict(test_x)
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(x, y, s=5, c='b', marker="o", label='real')
ax1.plot(test_x,test_y, c='r', label='NN Prediction')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Comment: I agree with your answer and it fits the curve much better.  I can see why ReLu is inappropriate for continuous functions but what is the reason that adam is not effective for such 'smooth & small data' problems?  I would like to know more about that.

Comment: Insightful answer. Thanks!